# libGL error: failed to create drawable

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I get this message when rviz or Gazebo crashes when I launch my project. After a lot of reseach I figured that it's related to the graphic drivers but after updating and checking that everything was fine I still get this issue.

Then, thanks to the [rviz troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting) wiki page I found that by simply turning off the hardware acceleration I don't have issues anymore and rviz and Gazebo always launch without crashing.

At first I was satisfied, but there is a downside : since the hardware acceleration is disabled the performances of Gazebo are significantly reduced which is really annoying. Since I know that the issue comes from the hardware acceleration being enabled or disabled is there any possibility to find an halfway solution by changing the configuration of this hardware acceleration (which I'm not at all familiar with) ?

**EDIT:**

I exported the project on a much more powerful computer (alienware) and never had the issue once so it was only because of the hardware not powerful enough I guess.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286985/libgl-error:-failed-to-create-drawable/) by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
Is this a VM?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
No I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the graphic card is Intel Ivybridge Mobile

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
Hm. This could be a driver issue then, as you already note. Do you have problems with other OGRE based 3D applications? Disabling acceleration would not seem like a viable work-around to me.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
With this computer I only use Ros related applications so I don't really know (in addition I don't really know which applications are using OGRE..), I should try to use moveit! then.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
MoveIt does not come with a visualiser. It just ships an RViz plugin. From your question text I get the impression you already tested that.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
I've found something talking about hardwware acceleration [here](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e3/ee/22/b3e3074b62a0a2/US8294723.pdf) (page 8 third paragraph) but I'm not sure if it's a similar issue to mine

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
That's a patent application document. I'm not sure how that is useful here.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
Well it's talking about an issue using harware acceleration with their application too.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-29**:
You can try `glxgears`, which is a decent (but not perfect) stand-in for `rviz`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
@Delb: what was the resolution here?

If you've solved it, please post an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-16**:
I've written it by editing my question but I will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue hasn't been solved with my current configuration but when exporting my project on a more powerful computer (with a better graphic card) this issue doesn't occur anymore. So the problem only comes from an hardware limitation.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1